# Asignar valor a cadena de caracteres en estructura

Tags: array, c, char

Estoy creando en C unas estructuras que tienen diferentes tipos de datos en su interior, en este caso me da problemas un array de char.

Defino la estructura fuera del main de esta manera:

```
struct persona {
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    int nota1;
    int nota2;
};
```

A la hora de crear una variable estructura de este tipo lo hago de la siguiente manera (ya dentro del main):

```
struct persona p1;
```

Si intento dar valor a la variable nota no me da ningún problema, lo hago así:

```
p1.nota = 7;
```

A la hora de dar valor al array de char es cuando me da un error. Le quiero dar valor dentro del programa y no pidiendo por teclado que me lo rellene:

```
p1.nombre = "FP";
```

Esta línea me da error porque me dice que no asigno bien el valor a un array pero... como lo hago?
No teine que ser dificil pero no veo documentación para este caso ya que todo lo que he visto es introduciendo un valor por teclado o a la hora de crear la estructura.

Un saludo y gracias a tod@s.

Un salduo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es lo mismo un puntero a char que un array de char.

### Puntero

El puntero a char se declara como `char *nombre`, por ejemplo, y éste puedes inicializarlo de dos formas:

```
nombre = "Manolo";
```

hará que el puntero apunte a una zona de memoria *estática* donde está pre-almacenada la cadena `"Manolo"` (la cual no podrás cambiar en tiempo de ejecución).

La otra forma es reservar memoria para la cadena y luego copiarla:

```
nombre = malloc(20);  // Sitio para 19 letras más el terminador
strcpy(nombre, "Manolo"); // Copia allí solo 6 letras más terminador, deja 13 posiciones libres
```

La primera línea busca una zona de memoria libre de 20 bytes y te retorna la dirección que ha encontrado, la cual asignamos al puntero. Una vez asignado, el puntero apunta a una zona en la que se pueden copiar caracteres, que es lo que después hace `strcpy()`. En este caso  la zona a que apunta el puntero no es *estática*, por lo que puedes manipular la cadena (pero cuidado no exceder el tamaño que reservaste!).

Hay una forma más, equivalente a la anterior pero que reserva sólo la cantidad necesaria para la cadena que vas a copiar:

```
nombre = strdup("Manolo");
```

Internamente hace un `malloc()` del tamaño apropiado (7 en este caso) y luego copia alli la cadena en cuestión, devolviéndote la dirección en la que ha dejado la copia.

### Array

Lo que tú tienes en cambio es un array. Es una zona de memoria ya reservada del tamaño que hayas especificado dentro de los corchetes (20 en este caso). El nombre del array actúa en C como un puntero a esa zona, por lo que puedes usar el segundo método antes visto:

```
char nombre[20];
strcpy(nombre, "Manolo");
```

Como ves `nombre` está haciendo las veces de un puntero, *pero no lo es*. Un puntero lo puedes hacer apuntar a otro lugar (por ejemplo asignándole lo que retorna `malloc()`), pero el símbolo `nombre` no se puede reasignar. Siempre apuntará a los 20 bytes del array.

Por eso no puedes hacer `nombre = "Manolo"` en este caso, porque eso intentaría reasignar la dirección a la que "apunta"  el símbolo `nombre` para hacerle apuntar a la zona de las cadenas estáticas.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Tengo esto un poco oxidado y no veía el error. Una explicación espectacular. Muchas gracias.